# Stop scrolling element and have it go back to where it started, when a certain page width is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the Spotify iframe to follow the user as they go down the page. I've achieved that with this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var $scrollingDiv = $("#spotifyIframe");

 $(window).scroll(function(){
 $scrollingDiv
  .stop()
  .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop())/1.5 + "px"}, "slow" );
  });
});
```

The only problem is that when the width of the page is smaller than 700px, the iframe goes below the paragraph, letting it scroll to infinity.

I tried putting the function in an `if` statement with `$(window).width() < 700`, and it sort of worked, but the only problem was that the scrolling function didn't start back up again, when the page width became bigger than 700px.

Here's what the website I'm making looks like:

[image: s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to the [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var $scrollingDiv = $("#spotifyIframe");
var largerThen700 = $(window).width() > 700;

$(window).resize(function(){
  largerThen700 = $(window).width() > 700;
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(largerThen700){
    $scrollingDiv
      .stop()
      .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop())/1.5 + "px"}, "slow");
    });
  }
});
```